# Where can I find a template for UITableViewCell icons?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, imageview

I know this isn't really a programming question, but I'm looking for a PSD template (or similar) to create UITableViewCell icon images that look like the ones in the Settings app... So basically the ones that look like mini-app icons.

Any ideas please? Thanks!

Comment: This falls into "shopping and recommendation" which aren't on topic for the SE network.

Comment: I find that a shame there isn't a place for questions like this on the SE network. For someone who is building an app on their own, questions like this are very relevant. I guess them's the rules, but I'd be grateful for any thoughts of where to ask questions like this in the future. Thanks.

Comment: I would also say my question does "generally relate to programming or software development in some way". It most definitely relates to software development in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this one](http://blog.cocoia.com/2010/iphone-4-icon-psd-file/).

Comment: Despite being off-topic, that's just what I needed thanks. The only shame is it doesn't have a retina version of the Settings icon. I can use the 57px home screen icon but it doesn't have the dark border... I'll keep looking but thanks :)